# Facebook Insights API Conversions are NOT matching Facebook Ads manager Results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

When trying to fetch Facebook insights API for the following action `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase` I always get less number than Facebook show on their ad manager, I tried to inspect their network calls and URL structure and I see they're using the same field `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase` to show `Results` I am not sure why the numbers are mis-matching. I tried to query from the Graph API and from my shell with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You may check `use_account_attribution_setting` and `use_unified_attribution_setting` in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights

Setting `use_unified_attribution_setting` to `true` worked for me.

Comment: That worked for me. But what does this even mean in layman’s terms? And why is the default like this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and found out that if you use an additional breakdown, FB will return less conversions. There might be a bug in their API when you use breakdowns.

I tried getting `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase` with
`'breakdowns' => 'hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone',`
and facebook retuned **5 conversions**.

if I **remove the breakdown** and get the data grouped daily I get **11 conversions** which is what Facebook Ads Manager shows